# How can I turn this IKEA cabinet into a secretary desk?

Tags: woodworking

I'm wanting to DIY a secretary desk out of the IKEA Hauga cabinet, which looks like this:

[image]

I want to add a drop-down desktop surface to the shelf portion using some drop front hinges. I'm unsure of what the best way to do it is, though. Should I try to have it rest completely vertically along the longer edge (red) when not in use, or should it partially rest at an angle along the shorter edge (green)? I want to leave the very top shelf alone so it can still be used as a shelf. This will also be mounted to the wall so weight is not a concern when the desk is in use.

Comment: What about a shelf on sliders that comes out when the doors are open - give room for your knees...

Comment: This might be a better fit for [woodworking.se].

Comment: Or *a silk purse from a sow's ear?*  The front is the wrong shape for a secretary desk, which has a straight sloped side from the point where the surface hinges. So you either have a gap at each side, or you need to fill the gap at each side.